# Wicked Pdf not generating on server. It worls on local fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wicked-pdf

I integrate wicked pdf in my app. On local it works fines but on server it giving an errro

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6186ms (ActiveRecord: 27.1ms)
RuntimeError (Failed to execute:

["/usr/local/bundle/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-q", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20170316-5-f2h6uc.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20170316-5-1qnsals.pdf"]

Error: PDF could not be generated!
```

Comment: Can you check if `wkhtmltopdf ` is installed on the server?

Comment: @harshs08 yes its installed

Comment: And is the path of installed binary same as `/usr/local/bundle/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: did you try with debug: true?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install and configure xserver on your server